# Understanding The Execution of Coroutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working in Unity, but this is really just a C# question so I hope this is the right section to post this. Anyways, I still have trouble visualizing the execution of scripts in my head, especially when there are more than one running and they all have different functions.

It's gotten more complicated recently as I've added Update, FixedUpdate, and Coroutine to my list of "When's this running"? Update and Fixed Update I get the gist.

As for Coroutine, I basically understand it's a type of function that gives me a more precise control of timing. It's the only way I know I can do "yield return new WaitForSeconds(i);"

My question is more about their execution order. For example if I call a coroutine from update(which runs once per frame) and that coroutine has a waitforseconds(10), then will pause execution of all script? Is there like one central clock running everything? Will Update not run again until the wait is up? What if I've got another script with an update function containing a different coroutine waiting as well and both run at the same time?

Maybe I'm being to vague. Hard to explain. I've read a couple of pieces of information online about coroutine, but nothing that really explains it in a way I can visualize it.

Comment: It will pause that particular routine, and nothing else.

Comment: So as that routine is paused will whatever lines were added after the "statcoroutine" continue to run?

Comment: Other coroutines will run independently of the paused one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first thing you need to know is that functions that use the `yield` keyword and return an `IEnumerable` are turned into iterators. It's syntactic sugar for writing a class that implements `IEnumerator`.

They're usually used in conjunction with `foreach` loops:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetFruits()
{
    yield return "Apple";
    yield return "Pear";
}

foreach (string fruit in GetFruits())
    Console.WriteLine(fruit);
```

What happens here is that `GetFruits` returns a generator object that implements `IEnumerator<string>`. Its `MoveNext` method runs part of the original `GetFruits` code each time it is called. Each call executes code up to the next `yield` statement, and uses the 'return value' of that `yield` to set the `Current` property of the generator.

The `foreach` loop results in code that calls `MoveNext` and that stores `Current` into the loop variable, which makes iteration much more readable, something like the following:

```
IEnumerator<string> fruitsGenerator = GetFruits().GetEnumerator();
while (fruitsGenerator.MoveNext())
{
    string fruit = fruitsGenerator.Current;
    Console.WriteLine(fruit);
}
```

But you're not limited to using iterators in loops. You can store a reference to a generator and call its `MoveNext` method, say, once per second. Or whenever a user presses a button. Or you could use the `Current` value to determine when `MoveNext` should be called again.

And that's exactly what Unity is doing. A coroutine is essentially a generator object (with some extra information, such as how much time is left until it should be called again). When a coroutine yields a `WaitForSeconds` object, Unity updates the waiting-time of that coroutine and will not call that coroutine's `MoveNext` method again until the waiting time is over.

Each 'update cycle', Unity calls `Update` on your game-objects and `MoveNext` on your coroutines, unless a coroutine is still in a 'waiting' state. A coroutine that's waiting is simply being skipped - it doesn't block any other code.

Comment: bravo mr pieter upvoted and might i suggest one noob thing i use with co routines , use a bool like this

public bool runOnce = false;

void Update(){      
     if(!runOnce){   StartCourotine(FunctionName()); runOnce = true; }
}

this way the coroutine will run just once and you can use the bool to start it whenever you want. Yes was not neccessary and not the best but i thought it will give you new ideas .